# What is the reason for putting the restriction on the divisor and remainder in division algorithm?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Division Algorithm :

Given $2$ numbers, $a$ and $b$, with $b>0$, $\exists ! \, q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a=bq+r$ with $0≤r<b$

While I understand this statement fully well and what it is trying to say. I fail to understand the reason for having,

1. $b>0$ why do you need $b$ to be greater than $0$. **I'm pretty much confident I have seen negative divisor countless times**
2. $0≤r<b$ what is the need for having $r≥0$? **Once again I'm pretty confident, I have seen negative remainders countless times**

Then why is it that Division Algorithm puts these restrictions?

What would happen if these conditions were not put on them?

Comment: I think $b>0$ is for simplicity while $0\leq r<b$ is for uniqueness of the remainder.

Comment: It could have had $b\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ and $t\leq r<b+t$ for some $t\in\mathbb Z$ and the whole thing would still work, though not be as clear and simple.

Answer (score 1):

1. Indeed, the condition is often written $0 \le r < |b|$ to cater for negative divisors.
2. Sure, you can replace $0 \le r < |b|$ by $-|b|/2 \le r < |b|/2$ for instance.

Comment: Where did you get the $-|b|/2$ and $|b|/2$ from? What if $b= 3$ so $-3/2 ≤ r < 3/2$?

Comment: @William, what about it? We get $-1,0,1$ as possible remainders, which is fine.

Comment: but then that contradicts with the first condition that $r≥0$ :/

Comment: @William, I was addressing your point #2: there is no need to require $r\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

These restrictions are used because

- they make the proofs easier,
- they can easily be circumvented.

Comment: How can they be "circumvented"?

Comment: @William: is it a great deal to consider the absolute values ?

Comment: nope, but I guess it would make for some tedious work.

Comment: also why is there a downvote on your answer? You write great answers, let me +1